# User lookup in my custom object is not showing the list of users available!

Tags: lookup, user

i have a custom object called ticket__c . it contains a field called user which is a lookup field for user object . while creating a new object onclicking the user lookup , it goes to a page but no user is present there!! why and how to resolve it? should i change any settings in user???

Comment: Have you tried searching in the lookup dialog that is shown?

Comment: It is a standard behavior, unfortunately, sometimes recent records are not shown quickly (you must wait) to have them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce shows the recently viewed records in the lookup dialog. That may be a reason. Can you please view any user and try.

Answer (score 0):

In classic inline edit will not show all the users.  Instead, click on the EDIT button on the page and it will give you option to select is what you are searching is a user or partner portal user.

Answer (score 0):

In classic inline edit will not show all the users.  Instead, click on the EDIT button on the page and it will give you option to select is what you are searching is a user or partner portal user.[image]